# arecord not working in ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, audio-recording, alsa, pulse-audio

arecord not working in ubuntu 9.10,  but Sound Recorder of ubuntu is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parec`, as arecord is not designed to be used with PulseAudio.

Answer (score 0):

arecord does not work with PulseAudio. Use:

```
killall pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

THE PULSE_SOURCE

```
PULSE_SOURCE=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo arecord -q -f cd -t wav | ffmpeg -loglevel panic -y -i - -ar 16000 -acodec flac file.flac
```

You may find which input you have with the command

```
pactl list |grep input
```